# statistics dice problem

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

If $5$ fair dice are thrown at the same time, how do you find the probability that there are three $1$'s and two $2$'s? The answer says its $5C2 \cdot (1/6)^5$ but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to arrange the two $2$s among the five dice, and for each such arrangement the $3$s are forced. Each such arrangement has $\left(\frac16\right)^5$ probability.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: First suppose we throw them one by one and show the probability on the sequence $1,1,1,2,2$ is equal to $(\frac{1}{6})^5 = \frac{1}{7776}$.

After that, in how many ways can we throw three ones and two twos?